# Выполнение функции по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: php, ajax, html5

Имеются 2 кнопки c id: button1 и button2.

Если была нажата кнопка "button1", то должна выполнится функция "abc", если "button2", то "abcd".

Как при нажатие на кнопку выполнить функцию на PHP в файле test.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с перезагрузкой страницы, если нужно без перезагрузки можно прикрутить AJAX или IFrame

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

test.php

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Update') {
    //action for update here
} else if ($_POST['action'] == 'Delete') {
    //action for delete
} else {
    //invalid action!
}
```

Comment: Кнопки(<button>) вне формы.

Comment: @Lyavontiy а что мешает заключить их в форму? Ну если без заключения в форму то только javascript/jquery - их та хоть есть возможность подключить?

Comment: Да, есть. Хотелось бы узнать как такое провернуть с помощью ajax